# how do i restrict users to access a trunk

Tags: svn

i am new to svn.in my project sombody are creating the branch from main onwards.So i need to restrict the users to create a branch.So any one can help how to restrict the users to access the main.

Comment: Telling them to or writing a Howto/Memo document is the surest way.

Answer (score 0):

In the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) it is explained very clear and in a way that is easy to follow.

> In the case of Apache, one needs to load the mod_authz_svn module and
>   then add the AuthzSVNAccessFile directive (within the httpd.conf file)
>   pointing to your own rules-file. If you're using svnserve, then you
>   need to make the authz-db variable (within svnserve.conf) point to
>   your rules-file.

The format of the rules-file is the following:

```
[calc:/branches]
harry = rw
sally = r
```

You can even define access groups or set default access to everybody or to nobody.